# Why am i unable to echo anything on the browser

Tags: php

I'm unable to modify the global variable inside the function nor display echo the message on the browser. Please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<body>
   <?php 
     $response = array(); 
    function() { 
        global $response['res']="hello"; 
        echo json_encode($response); 
     } 
    echo "hello";
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't echo because it doesn't run because it doesn't compile. `global $response['res']="hello";` is two statements combined into once (this doesn't work). Try `global $response; $response['res']="hello";`

Comment: You need to name your function and remove `global $response[...]`.

Comment: Syntax error: response['res']="hello"; where is `$`

Comment: **Don't** modify the code in the question to match the suggestions you get in comments! **Fix the code in your program.**

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up your code a little bit and added a name to the function, now I see `hello` in the browser. The function also needs to `return` rather than echo, because you can then echo the function like `echo test()`. This should sort your problem:

```
<?php
$response = array();
function test() {
    global $response;
    $response['res'] = "hello";
    return json_encode($response);
}
echo test();
?>
```

Full HTML code that should be placed in a `.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $response = array();
            function test() {
                global $response;
                $response['res'] = "hello";
                return json_encode($response);
            }
            echo test();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And output in the browser:

[image]

Comment: I saved the file as xyz.html and and inserted the exact code as u have written but i dont get any output on the browser,

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$response = array();
function test() {
    global $response;
    $response['res'] = "hello";
    return json_encode($response);
}
echo test();
?>

</body>
</html>
 this is my whole code

Comment: Well you won't if you've saved it as `.html` this code is working as I've tested it locally. You may have other code blocking it. Create a new `.php` file and you'll see the JSON data

Comment: okay I have saved the file as .php extension and copied the exact code in the new file created  but it still doesnt give any output

Comment: As you can see in the answer this is working fine, I can only assume you have a different issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. I did not realize the localhost thing. I was just executing it like a normal html program in my desktop folder. Didn't realise it require php engine

Comment: No problem at all @GraceJochu you can also see it working here - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0dmq-gfeg just click the run button (f9) :)

Comment: @GraceJochu been a while, any chance of an accept on this?